# Understanding the symbol <A,B> in affine spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, affine-geometry

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> A subset F of an affine space is an affine subspace if and only if for
>   all points A and B of F, the inclusion `<A, B>` ⊂ F holds.

However, i don't understand what `<A, B>` is intended to represent in this context, can you explain me ?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably the line containing $A$ and $B$ (a one dimensional affine subspace). The notation should be defined somewhere earlier in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two points, the notation $\langle A, B\rangle$ means the line through those points. Explicitly, we have

$$\langle A,B \rangle = \{tA+(1-t)B : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. How would you explicitly give the affine hull of two points? Also what is the definition of an affine space? Is it a translated vectorspace? That is certainly equivalent to $A,B \in F \implies \langle A, B \rangle \subseteq F$ as I have written above.

Comment: My apologies. I was misled by the word "connecting", and didn't notice that your definition had $\ t\in\mathbb{R}\ $ rather than $\ t\in [0,1]\ $. I should have waited till I was properly awake before trying to comment. I have now made a minor edit to your answer and changed my downvote to an upvote.